# react-hook-form empty context

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I created a library with a few components. Some of the components are based on `react-hook-form`, but in my main app I have a problem rendering the form component.

```js
import React from "react";
import Button from "@evgvis/test-lib/dist/base/Button";
import Form from "@evgvis/test-lib/dist/forms/Form";
import Input from "@evgvis/test-lib/dist/forms/Input";
    
    export default function App() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Button title="google" url="https://google.com" />
                <Form>
                    <Input name="test" label="test" />
                </Form>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

As result I receive an error:

```
TypeError
Cannot destructure property 'register' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is null.
```

I created `test-lib` with a few components in [github](https://github.com/evgvis/test-lib), then published it to [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@evgvis/test-lib), and created [csb](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-sutherland-wo2hp?file=/src/App.js)

Can you review it ;)

Answer (score 0):

i solved this issue) 
basically what i need it is just adding react-hook-form as external library in [webpack config](https://github.com/evgvis/test-lib/blob/main/webpack.config.js)
and now, [csb](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-sutherland-wo2hp?file=/src/App.js) is working :)