# How to add react-hook-form as an external library in webpack?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, react-hook-form

I'm making a form in which I need to integrate [react-dropzone](https://react-dropzone.js.org/) with [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/), for that, I based myself in this discussion on Github: https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/discussions/2146.
However, when destructuring the useFormContext, as follows:

```
const { control } = useFormContext();
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'control' of 
'(0 , react_hook_form__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.useFormContext)(...)' as it is null.
```

I did some research and found this question: [react-hook-form empty context](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65726804/16713671), where the developer had a problem very similar to mine. The found solution was

> basically what i need it is just adding react-hook-form as external
> library in webpack config and now, csb is working :)

I know little about the webpack, especially inside Nextjs. But after researching and reading the documentation, this was my try:

```
/next.config.js

module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, options) => {
    config.externals.push({
      'react-hook-form': 'react-hook-form',
    });

    return config;
  },
  ...
}
```

But the error remains the same. Do you know how I can fix this problem?

Comment: Did you wrap your form with the `FormProvider` component? See [`useFormContext` docs](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useformcontext).

Comment: @juliomalves you're right, I forgot to wrap my form! I've been having this problem for two days now, and now it's solved... Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks to @juliomalves' comment, I solved the problem. The problem was that I forgot to wrap my form with the `FormProvider` component.
The error was given because there was no context to provide `control` to my `useFormContext`, so there was no way to unstruct it.